# Java substring method giving IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, methods, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to separate `String [] adr = {"Tel Iva +38712345", "Mail Iva ivag@gmail.com", "Tel Ana +12345678"}` by looking at each of the element's first word. If the first word is `Mail`, it goes to `String [] m`, and if the first word is `Tel`, it goes to `String [] t`.

Here is my code:

```
public static void rep(String a, String []adr) {

    int mail=0, tel=0;
    for (int i=0; i<adr.length; i++) {
        if(adr[i].substring(0, 3).equals("Mail")) {
            mail++;
        }
        else tel++;
    }
    String [] m = new String [mail];
    String [] t = new String [tel];

    for(int i=0; i<adr.length; i++) {
        if(adr[i].substring(0, 4).equals("Mail")) {
            m[i]=adr[i].substring(5);
        }

        else t[i]=adr[i].substring(4);
        System.out.println(adr[i].substring(0, 4));
    }
}
```

But for some reason unknown to me, I get

`Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

which points at line `m[i]=adr[i].substring(5)`. I really do not understand why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you are using the same index variable to store mails and tels in the second loop. you should use two additional indexes, one for each array, and increment them as required.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Thank you, now I've noticed the mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct Solution. you need to two indices to track m and t array traversal.

public static void rep(String a, String []adr) {

```
    int mail=0, tel=0;
    for (int i=0; i<adr.length; i++)
    {
        if(adr[i].substring(0, 4).equals("Mail")) {
            mail++;
        }
        else tel++;
    }
    String [] m = new String [mail];
    String [] t = new String [tel];
    int mIndex =0, tIndex = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<adr.length; i++) {
        if(adr[i].substring(0, 4).equals("Mail")) {
            m[mIndex]=adr[i].substring(4);
            mIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            t[tIndex]=adr[i].substring(4);
            tIndex++;
        }
        System.out.println(adr[i].substring(0, 4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well You can try this method, I once coded same type of problem when I was learning Java for the my academics. Well you can also try StringTokenizer  method to do the same. Maybe they works better. I am expecting that you are going to insert the whole string not splitted one.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.*;

public class stringtoken{


  public static void main(String args[]){


         List<String> m=new ArrayList<String>();
         List<String> t=new ArrayList<String>();

         String[] s={"Tel Iva +38712345", "Mail Iva ivag@gmail.com", "Tel Ana +12345678"};

         for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){

                 if(s[i].indexOf("Tel")==0){

                       t.add(s[i]);
                 }
                 else if(s[i].indexOf("Mail")==0){
                       m.add(s[i]);
                 }
         }

         for(int i=0;i<m.size();i++){
                System.out.println(m.get(i));
         }
         for(int i=0;i<t.size();i++){
               System.out.println(t.get(i));
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly index you used in the substring method are correct and I will only talk about index of the array :

> String [] adr = {"Tel Iva +38712345", "Mail Iva ivag@gmail.com", "Tel Ana +12345678"}

By this data,

**mail array**'s **size** will be **1**, max index can use for mail array is **0**

**tel array**'s **size** will be **2**, max index can use for tel array is **1**

```
for(int i=0; i<adr.length; i++) {
    if(adr[i].substring(0, 4).equals("Mail")) {
        m[i]=adr[i].substring(5);
    }

    else t[i]=adr[i].substring(4);
    System.out.println(adr[i].substring(0, 4));
}
```

In this loop :

LOOP 1 : i = 0 -> t[0]=xxx; -> OK

LOOP 2 : i = 1 -> m[1]=xxx; -> ERROR, because size of m array is 1, index can only be 0

PS : you need to check the index used in substring method

Answer (score 0):

suppose this sample address array (your parameter adr[])

```
adr[0] = Maila@a.com
adr[1] = Tele123456
adr[2] = Mailb@a.com
adr[3] = Tele123456
adr[4] = Mailc@a.com
```

After your first loop which is assign values to int mail and tel

```
mail = 3;
tel = 2
```

so your m and t array looks like below.

```
    String [] m = new String [3];
    String [] t = new String [2];
```

What happen is in your last for looping for adr (you parameter array) length which is 5.

and try to assign values to m or t, by index of adr array.

Ex : `adr[3] = Tele123456`

on your second loop when **i = 3** your getting this value and try to assign this value to

**`t[3] = 123456`**

where actually t size is 2 and then it occur array out of bound exception.

Hope you understood the issue on your code.

Rather than array for m and t use List.

Consider below example.

```
public static void rep(String a, String []adr) {

    List<String> mails = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> teles = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<adr.length; i++) {
        if(adr[i].substring(0, 3).equals("Mail")) {
            mails.add(adr[i].substring(5));
        } else {
           mails.add(adr[i].substring(5));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note : please fix compile errors if there.